# Assign Checkbox.checked value invoke checked event in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

I have a form with some text boxes and check boxes.Im doing calculation from the values on textbox.Depends on the checkbox status the output values get changed.
Same time, im saving all these data in to excel sheet including the checkbox status in to the excel sheet. Later i will import these data to the form for further calculation. So when i import the values from excel to form,when i change the status of checkbox as checked. Then Tempmetric_CheckedChanged() function get invoked and it creates some error because at this point i dont have all input values for calculation.
How can i avoid that? Just i have one idea to set flag in Import function and i will check this flag in Tempmetric_CheckedChanged() to avoid further working.

```
Private Sub Tempmetric_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Tempmetric.CheckedChanged

        If Tempmetric.Checked Then
            STempUnit.Text = "F"
            FTempunit.Text = "F"
        Else
            STempUnit.Text = "C"
            FTempunit.Text = "C"
        End If
        Button1_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs()) // i have to use flag before this function call
    End Sub


    Private Sub SaveBTn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBTn.Click  

            Dim metric As Integer    
            If Tempmetric.Checked Then
                metric = 1
            Else
                metric = 0
            End If    
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, 1) = "Metric"
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, 1).Font.Bold = True
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, 2) = metric
End Sub

Private Sub ImpInputBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ImpInputBtn.Click
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet       

        For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count

        SamTemp.Text = xlWorkSheet.Cells(4, 2).Value.ToString
        FormTemp.Text = xlWorkSheet.Cells(5, 2).Value.ToString
            If xlWorkSheet.Cells(7, 2).Value = 1 Then
                Tempmetric.Checked = True
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

IS there any other possible way to do that? What is the difference between     'Checked' and 'CheckState' property?

Comment: Using a flag to enable / disable events in the way you describe is a standard technique.

Comment: "Checked" can assume only two values, the boolean values (true/false), the "CheckState" can have three values, checked/unchecked/indeterminate. The two property change at the same time, checked=true / unchecked=false / indeterminate=true.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1) Change the event of "Tempmetric" from CheckedChanged to Click.

2) Add a global boolean variable "Importing" and in your function of import from Excel you set it before to "true" and check this variable on CheckedChanged event.

Comment: I tried that first solution and it works well as i wanted.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to remove the OnCheckedChanged handler from the checkboxes, import data from the Excel sheet and set the checked property on the checkboxes, and finally reassign the OnChecked handlers:

```
Public Class MyForm
    Private Sub ImportButton_Click(...)
        RemoveHandler MyCheckbox.CheckChanged, AddressOf Me.MyCheckbox_CheckedChanged
        ImportDataAndSetCheckboxs()
        AddHandler MyCheckbox.CheckChanged, AddressOf Me.MyCheckbox_CheckedChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub ImportDataAndSetCheckboxs()
        ' ... Do work to import and update checkboxes
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyCheckbox_CheckedChanged(...) Handles MyCheckbox.CheckedChanged
        ' ... Whatever work needs to get done here
    End Sub
End Class
```

Removing the event handler should make it so you can update the checkboxes without having to deal with the events causing errors.